# Rails, DataMapper & JSON issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-datamapper

I've some trouble with a really simple Rails setup using DataMapper. This is my model:

```
class Capture
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :identifier, String
  property :caption, Text
 end
```

Now I add a new capture in Rails console by:

Capture.create(:identifier => '12345', :caption => 'Foo bar foo')

If I try to get all captures by

Capture.all

... i get a

```
[#<Capture @id=1 @identifier="12345" @caption=<not loaded>>]
```

First question: what does the "not loaded" mean in this case? But the trouble I have is I cannot convert the result to JSON:

Capture.all.to_json

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `encode_json' for #<Capture @id=1 @identifier="12345" @caption=<not loaded>>
```

Is it a DM issue? How to encapsulate such a result into JSON? Many thanks in advance ;-) Chris.

Comment: OK, found it out: to use to_json in DataMapper I need dm-serializer as Gem. Works fine now ;-)

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: @Simon's right, instead of adding `[SOLVED]` to the title of your answer, just answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for the first question: `not loaded` means that data loading is delayed until actually needed because Text property is lazy by default. http://datamapper.org/articles/spotlight_on_laziness.html